# ASP.Net MVC 5 using webconfig credentials and Membership.ValidateUser method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I am storing a single credential in my Web.config file the usual way:

```
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="2880">
        <credentials passwordFormat="Clear">
          <user name="admin" password="123" />
        </credentials>
      </forms>
    </authentication>
```

I am fully aware of the TOP NOTCH security and password strength :).

Then in my Custom AuthProvider class I validate the user the usual (old) way:

```
bool result = FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(username, password);
```

And it works fine, however, that method is deprecated (obsolete).
So I want to use the new way (which I believe to be the right thing):

```
bool result = Membership.ValidateUser(username, password);
```

But I get exception:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

There obviously isn't truly a problem accessing the database, since I am showing "unauthenticated" content from it perfectly fine.

So my question is... what is the new solution to save credentials in the Web.config without using deprecated methods? I figured others might run into the same issue and I am very curious to understand why this is happening...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

there is no equivalent in the api for **FormsAuthentication.Authenticate** in MVC 5
if you use **Membership.ValidateUser** you need to define membership in webconfig usually the server that give role to the user like a active directory server.